# Finding parent element in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

**I cant get this to work in IE9** Other versions are fine, fine in any browser. I need to add a class to the parent 'li' when you click in the text input.

```
$(document).on('focus', '.fieldSlick', function(){
    $(this).parents("li:first").addClass('input--filled');
});
$(document).on('blur', '.fieldSlick', function(){
    if(!$.trim(this.value).length){
        $(this).parents("li:first").removeClass('input--filled');
    }
});
```

This should be very simple, but IE9 isn't behaving. What am I missing? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5718svm/1/)

Comment: If you are looking for immediate parent then try $(this).parent("li")

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/nz2zhajo/ Just curious Id `li` child of `ul` its not in your fiddle

Comment: The html is invalid. Wrap in ul. Does this work? Works in IE10 http://fiddle.jshell.net/mplungjan/g039tzxx/show/light/

Comment: IE10 isn't an issue, my original code works there as expected. Nothing seems to work for IE9

Comment: Anybody's IE9 or only yours?

Comment: Shit at this point, probably just mine. Yours worked on a different IE9 VM, thank you. I would gladly accept your answer if that matters. I really appreciate it, why does .parents('li') work but not .parent()?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with the [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(document).on('focus', '.fieldSlick', function(){
  //$(this).parent().addClass('input--filled');
  $(this).closest("li").addClass('input--filled');
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/c5718svm/2/)

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Have you fixed the [html-markup](http://jsfiddle.net/c5718svm/3/) (wrapping your `li` inside an `ul`) as there might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your jQuery version to 2.1 or higher. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcgx42j1/). The Code is still the same

```
$(document).on('focus', '.fieldSlick', function(){
  //$(this).parent().addClass('input--filled');
  $(this).parents("li:first").addClass('input--filled');
});
$(document).on('blur', '.fieldSlick', function(){
  if(!$.trim(this.value).length){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('input--filled');
  }
});
```